# Downgrading Phonegap

Tags: cordova, extjs, blackberry

It seems phonegap version 3.5 doesn't support blackberry( using npm install -g phonegap on node.js installs phonegap version 3.5). So i was trying to downgrade phonegap to version 2.9.by using nmp install -g phonegap@2.8.0 but it gives error on node.js. Please advise.

Comment: I am not sure that version was on npm.

Comment: Ok, try `npm install -g phonegap@2.9.0-0.13.2`

Answer (score 0):

you can manually download phonegap  2.9 and configure your project from http://phonegap.com/install/

and for plugins you need to follow that procedure which was use before 3.0 and without cmd